# While Inserting Time in to mysql database through django it stores different time

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, timezone

While Inserting time in to mysql database through django project it is stored as standard Greenwich time but not my standard time GMT+5.30. Example when i am giving 5.30 PM through django it is stored as 12.00 AM.How it could be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.4+ with `USE_TZ=True` the datetimes are converted to UTC when they are passed to MySQL. When they are retrieved back, Django converts these datetimes to the timezone in use.

If you want to store local times ([usually not a good idea](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime)) you can turn off timezone management: `USE_TZ=False`.

If you want to store TZ information on DB, you will have to switch to PostgreSQL.

Django and timezones documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 0):

Did you change TimeZone in settings.py file?